# Which statistical analysis to compare proportions between multiple groups?

Tags: multiple-comparisons, proportion

I can’t figure out the stats to use for my problem.

I have 2 groups, each with 100 patients. These groups each have a different primary treatment of interest.

I have 3 different secondary treatments within these groups.

I also have an outcome which is expressed as positive outcome/number of trials.

The data is something like this:

| Group | Treatment | Positive_Outcomes | Trials |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | TreatA | 4 | 4 |
| A | TreatA | 8 | 20 |
| A | TreatB | 0 | 3 |
| A | TreatC | 2 | 6 |
| B | TreatA | 5 | 9 |
| B | TreatA | 2 | 2 |
| B | TreatB | 3 | 5 |
| B | TreatC | 5 | 5 |

I want to ask 2 questions… firstly if there is a difference in the proportion of positive outcomes between group A and B. Secondly, is using the primary treatment (Group) affect the outcomes of the secondary treatments differently (TreatA, B, C).

I believe it may be some kind of regression analysis to deal with the proportion but I’m not sure how to go about it. I am using r for my analysis if you could suggest useful packages.

EDIT:
The dependent variable that I want to actually compare is the proportion of Positive_Outcomes .... (1, 0.4, 0, 0.33 etc) and I'm not sure how this fits in a logistic regression if I could please ask for some help and clarification on this.

Comment: Welcome to cv, Biologist99! You are right, it is a kind of regression analysis, namely *logistic regression*. This can be done in R with a function called `glm` - you don't need extra packages for that. glm stands for "Generalized linear model" - have you heard of logistic regression or generalized linear models before? A quick question: in the table you showed (good idea!), the trial numbers do not add up to 100. (It does not matter, really, just curious)

Comment: Is each row patient?

Comment: Ah @dmitry, this is likely to be the answer to my last question :-) Now that the table is easier to read it makes sense.

Comment: A key question is whether this is from a randomized experiment. If so, some form of logistic regression probably makes sense. If not, things are much more tricky and you need something to account for the treatment assignment mechanism (e.g. if sicker people always get treatment A, because it is more efficacious but also has more side effects, treatment A may still have worse outcomes than other treatments despite being more efficacious).